# iPad retina screen recording

Tags: ios, ipad, opengl-es-2.0, retina-display, video-recording

Two parts:

1. Correct me if I'm wrong, but there **isn't** a standard video file format that holds 2048 x 1536 frames? (i.e. recording the full resolution of the iPad retina is impossible?)
2. My app uses a glReadPixels call to record the screen, and appends the pixel buffers to an AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor. If the video needs to be resized to export, what's the best way to do this? I'm trying right now with AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstructions and CGAffineTransforms, but it's not working. Any ideas?

Thanks

Sam

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes , it is possible. My app is also taking big frame video .
2. Don't use glReadpixels it causes a lot of delay especially if you record big frames as 2048 x 1536

Since iOS 5.0 you can use a faster way using  texture cash ([link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVBasicVideoOutput/Introduction/Intro.html))

Comment: What video formats? And is there a way to use the texture caches with screen recording: it's the content on the screen I'm recording, not the camera feed.

Comment: .MOV and yes you can record OpenGL buffer it is just rendering the screen to backing texture cache. In my case, Texturing from Cam -> Shading -> Rendering -> Recording so just keep texturing

Comment: Can you get a texture ref from the renderbuffer?

Comment: No, that's impossible. I can get a texture ref from the texture cash . This is a basic logic of that , after you make a texture cash using IOS API,you can render your renderbuffer to temp texture buffer ( backing buffer ) supported by apple . and then you can record video using this cash ref.

Comment: In the docs here (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreVideo/Reference/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef) it says that the target can be GL_TEXTURE2D or GL_RENDERBUFFER: what does that mean?

Comment: I'm not sure but when I tried with GL_RENDERBUFFER I had error. Anyway, no matter what, the method creates a live binding between the CVImageBuffer and underlying CVOpenGLESTexture texture object so even if you set it as GL_RENDERBUFFER that doesn't mean you have a texture ref from renderbuffer buffer. just try it's easy